# Getting Filenotfoundexception while writing file when deployed the java application in CAE container

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ini

Iam trying to write a file and iam getting Filenot found exception /home/jboss/src/main/resources/config.ini.

The use case is there is a secretid which rotates for every 10 days and iam getting this secretid through API and want to store in a file in the application.So whenever the application is restarted it will pick the latest secretid.

To read a file iam using getResourceAsStream and iam able to read the file successfully
prop.load(PropertiesUtil.class.getResourceAsStream("config.ini")

To write a file we cannot use getResourceAsStream right (getResourceAsStream is for only reading files).

Wini ini = new Wini(new File("src/main/resources/config.ini"));
ini.put("id",currnetId);
In my local it is working fine.I have deployed this application to cae containers.Iam getting the below exception

Filenot found exception : /home/jboss/src/main/resources/config.ini

How to update the file by using relative path in the running application in java in CAE container.

Can i create a folder on the application startup in a location and can i use that folder to store config file.

Could you please help on this

Comment: Is it a web app?

Comment: @g00se , It is a spring boot application.It is rest service application

Comment: I don't really do Spring but generically you should probably be looking at `getRealPath`. Certainly forget IDE paths. "/config.ini" should be the path

Comment: @g00se , The use case is there is a secretid which rotates for every 10 days and iam getting this secretid through API and want to store in a file in the application.So whenever the application is restarted it will pick the latest secretid.

Comment: @g00se , Can i create a folder on the application startup in a location and can i use that folder to store config file.,,but that will be deleted when i restart the application right..that is not possible i think

Comment: @g00se , will this work..? can u please suggest .Wini ini = new Wini(new File("/config.ini"));

Comment: In a word, no. That means "create the path to file 'config.ini' which is off the root of the *filesystem*"

Comment: Generally speaking, this is a problem of strategy. You should really write to a file *outside* of your app or you could get unwanted effects. I would have a property *in* your app config containing the location of that path. Off `user.home` is probably best